# remove other color/ noise by using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm doing research on removing the background noise from the texts, I already knew these texts will have the fixed color, but the noise can be very different.

for example, I want to remove the rest part from the image but only remains the text "Do it now!", my plan is doing the pre-process for this image first, remove the noise, and send the processed image to tesseract to do OCR, see the picture here: 
[image]

I'm new to opencv and have some basics knowledge of opencv, could someone point me a direction so I can learn it?

right now, tesseract cannot detect any text from this image

```
[from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import *

if __name__ =="__main__":
    pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'))) # print nothing here.
```

Comment: May you provide the image?

Comment: thank you @Zhubei-Federer, I don't have enough credit to post a image here, but I've added a image link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use hsv mask:

```
def img_hsv_mask(img):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)           
    lower_hsv = np.array([0, 0, 150])           
    upper_hsv = np.array([255, 20, 255])         
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_hsv, upper_hsv) 
    cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv2.waitKey (0)
```

out put mask image as this:

[image]

now you can use OCR with mask image:

```
code = pytesseract.image_to_string(mask, lang='eng')
print(code)
>>~ Do itnow
```

Comment: thank you, now I'm working on how to mark your reply as the answer.

Comment: one more question, how do you know the parameter [0,0,150] and [255,20,255] is the correct value? I searched hsv color on google and tried to convert it back to RGB, but it just make me more confused, thank you very much

Comment: maybe you can reference this page: http://colorizer.org/.
BTW,the parameters is just try and error,you can adjust it yourself~